# Is it possible to make a transparent background color on javascript (p5js)?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, transparent, p5.js

Hello i was wondering if its possible to make the backround of a canvas looks transparent (no color). The code snippet below shows an example of what im trying to explain.. Please if you have any suggestions let me know

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  /* How to make a transparent color????? */
  background(220);
  rect(100,100,100,200);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [It's right there in the documentation.](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/background)

Comment: As stated in the documentation, you can use rgba to specifiy a transparent background: background('rgba(123, 123, 123, 0.5)')

Comment: remove `background(220);` it wont draw any background, which will make canvas transparent.

Comment: Not adding background seems to be a solution.. it works thanks @Durga

Answer (score 3):

It depends on exactly what you mean by transparent.

If you want it to be completely transparent, then you're probably looking for the `clear()` function. More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/clear), but to summarize: the `clear()` function acts like the `background()` function but makes everything transparent instead of any particular color.

If you want your background to be partially transparent, like a color that you can still see through, then you also need to add an alpha argument to your call to the `background()` function. Again, more info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/background), but here's an example:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  clear();
  background(220, 10);
  rect(100, 100, 100, 200);
}
```

Note that you still need to call `clear()`, otherwise the transparent background is drawn on top of old scenes, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Another option I found is to not call the background() function:

```js
var check = false;
function setup(){
  createCanvas(500,500);
}
function draw(){

  fill(random(255),random(255),random(255));
  rect(100,100,50,90);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your meaning of transparent.

If you want the transparent like displaying trail in your animation, add alpha. Under/

```
background(0, 50);
```

The '50' number is alpha. The '0' number is black.

Answer (score 0):

In your draw() function call the background function with the CSS property rgba and alpha=0:

```
function draw() {
   clear();
   background('rgba(255,255,255, 0)');
   ...
   ...
}
```